# Nesting a LINQ query inside a where clause of another query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

How would I combine the following two queries into a single query?

```
    using (var ctx = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        int parentId = await ctx.MenuEntity.Where(m => m.Title == thisVariable).Select(m => m.MenuId).SingleAsync();
        menuEntityList = await ctx.MenuEntity.Where(m => m.ParentId == parentId).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is equivalent to EXISTS in sql

```
 var menuEntityList = context.MenuEntity.Where(
 m => context.MenuEntity.Where(m =>
 m.Title == thisVariable).Any(d => d.MenuId == m.ParentId)
                ).ToList();
```

I get Query with Profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[MenuId], [m].[ParentId], [m].[Title]
FROM [MenuEntity] AS [m]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [MenuEntity] AS [m0]
    WHERE [m0].[Title] = @__thisVariable_0 
    AND [m0].[MenuId] = [m].[ParentId])'
,N'@__thisVariable_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__thisVariable_0=N'Org'
```

Comment: Even though the other answers do the job, I like this one the best because of strictly sticking to method syntax, plus posting the converted sql query helped me understand better what the linq query is doing.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different syntax from [the answer by @AztecCodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76376833/14868997), more like an `IN` in SQL

```cs
using (var ctx = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
   menuEntityList = await (
        from m in ctx.MenuEntity
        where ctx.MenuEntity
            .Where(x => x.Title == thisVariable)
            .Select(x => x.MenuId)
            .Contains(m.ParentId)
        select m
   ).ToListAsync();
}
```